# How does spring communicate with the context in code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
public class ApplicationLauncher {

    public static void main(String []args) throws LifecycleException
    {
        Tomcat tomcat=new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setPort(8080);
        tomcat.getConnector();

        Context ctx=tomcat.addContext("",null);
        WebApplicationContext appCtx = createApplicationContext(ctx.getServletContext());
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet=new DispatcherServlet(appCtx);
        Wrapper servlet=Tomcat.addServlet(ctx,"gello", dispatcherServlet);
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/*");
        tomcat.start();
    }
```

how does tomcat call context in code, i am trying to see how it works under the hood but here I am just confused, I have intialized ctx with tomcat.addcontext and wrapper servlet through Tomcat.addServlet but when tomcat.start() executes how does it call call the context